# "No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase" Error shown but has been initiated already

Tags: flutter, firebase

Notice a few questions here regarding this topic, tried the solutions but still no fix to the problem in my code. I am making a sign up screen for my app in Android Studio, but when I press submit signup form, Flutter gives me this error, although I have initiated Firebase.initializeApp() already in my main.dart file. Why is this showing and how do I fix this?

In my Main.dart file

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]); // This makes the phone locked in portrait mode, preventing landscape usage
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  DarkThemeProvider themeChangeProvider = DarkThemeProvider();

  void getCurrentAppTheme() async {
    themeChangeProvider.setDarkTheme = await themeChangeProvider.darkThemePrefs
        .getTheme(); //calling dark theme provider to call dark theme prefs method
  } // fetching theme from shared preferences, if user chose value, last value chosen will be fetched and applied

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentAppTheme();
    super.initState();
    Firebase.initializeApp().whenComplete(() {
      print("Intialised");
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  final Future<FirebaseApp> _firebaseInitialisation = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _firebaseInitialisation,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const MaterialApp(
```

When pressing the button to register in a separate file, the code is

```
bool _isLoading = false; 
  void _submitFormOnRegister() async {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    if (isValid) {
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
      try { //useful to catch any error
        await authInstance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword( //Look below for what authInstance is
            email: _emailTextController.text.toLowerCase().trim(),
            password: _passwordTextController.text.trim());
        print('Registered');
      } on FirebaseException catch (error) {
        UniversalFunctions.errorDialog(subtitle: '${error.message})', context: context);
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      } catch (error) {
        UniversalFunctions.errorDialog(subtitle: '$error', context: context);
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

the authInstance is in a separate file:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

final FirebaseAuth authInstance  = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User? user = authInstance.currentUser;
final uid = user!.uid;
```

I suspected the button was activating before the firebase.initialise was being called but I'm not sure as I stated it at the front in the main. I saw a solution to add it to the

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

But it does not work (due to the other code having it locking screen format) and it doesn't work when I remove that.

EDIT: Fixed it, needed to install flutterfire CLI and to use the code:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
```

);

Comment: The `initializeApp` in your final snippet looks quite different from what's in bullet 4 of this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#initialize-firebase

Comment: That fixed it! Did not have flutterfire in and after a bit of tinkering it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear you got it working, Alek.  --- I wrote a quick answer below for folks who end up in this situation and in this page in the future. I now see that you just added it to your question too, but that's not a common practice here on Stack Overflow (as the system doesn't recognize that as an answer, folks are unlikely to see it either).

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing any configuration data to the `initializeApp` call, which means that the SDK assumes it exists "somewhere in its context" (typically this is on web and means you configure it in the JS include file).

That's not the most common way to initialize Firebase these days anymore though, so I have a feeling you may not have been following the steps in the documentation on [adding Firebase to your Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup). After following that guide, your code should like bullet 4 of [step 3](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#initialize-firebase).

Answer (score 0):

You can add this dependency too in `pubspecs.yaml` file

`firebase_core`  and try after re running the app.

Comment: My pubspecs.yaml file has 
  firebase_core: ^2.23.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.14.1

Comment: Can you share your main.dart code where you initialzing firebase and make use of it

Comment: I did, bottom of the first code box. the firebase is initialised there (In the futurebuilder), and then called in the submit form code box which is the second one

Comment: you wrote this final FirebaseAuth authInstance  = FirebaseAuth.instance; before
await Firebase.initializeApp(); ?

Comment: Oh is that what's causing the issue? so I have to add that after like in the main.dart file

Comment: Might be you can try that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to initialize Firebase:

```html
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

You should initialize and `await` it before the main widget which is `MyApp()`.

What you are doing is initializing Firebase in the initState which is not an async function that is why you are getting and error.

If doing this causes an error with your other code, then that error is what you need to resolve.

Comment: Did this after but problem was still there. I found the solution with using: await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

Comment: Also had to install flutterfire CLI which I missed out